cleveref labels appendices as sections
In the most recent MiKTeX and TexLive distributions, cleveref mislabels appendices:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\cref{app:a}

\appendix

\section{An appendix}
\label{app:a}

\end{document}

yields

This issue emerged for me after updating all packages (for the first time in around a year, I think), so unfortunately I have no hints for what the origin of the change is.

This is a known issue, see https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/362. In that issue, Ulrike suggests the following workaround.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\AddToHook{cmd/appendix/before}{\crefalias{section}{appendix}}

\begin{document}

\cref{app:a}

\appendix

\section{An appendix}
\label{app:a}

\end{document}

As cleveref has numerous issues with current LaTeX, you should consider moving to the actively-maintained zref-clever. With that package, your example has no issues.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref-clever}

\begin{document}

\zcref{app:a}

\appendix

\section{An appendix}
\label{app:a}

\end{document}


